# Local function declaration inside namespace

Tags: c++, namespaces, function-declaration

In such a situation

```
namespace n {
    void f() {
        void another_function();
    }
}
```

Should  the function `another_function` be defined inside the namespace `n` or outside? VS  2012 (with the [November CTP](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2012/11/02/visual-c-c-11-and-the-future-of-c.aspx)) says it should be outside, and GCC 4.7.2 on the Mac says it should be inside. If I do the wrong one, I get undefined symbol errors from the linkers.

I generally trust GCC to be more compliant to the standard, but this is C++ and you can never be sure.

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: @BillyONeal because `another_function` is an implementation detail and `f` is a template.

Comment: But declaring `another_function` inside `f` doesn't make it less visible than `f`. It will just cause multiple definition errors if someone happens to define their own `n::another_function`.

Comment: @BillyONeal no client will/should be putting things into my namespace since it's a library. It does make it slightly less visible since they have to work to get the prototype. Is there a better way to do  it?

Comment: I would just put the prototype inside `your_namespace::detail`. That's what boost does in these situations anyway. The convention is that anything inside a namespace `detail` are implementation details.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

C++11 3.5 (as well as C++03)

> **7** When a block scope declaration of an entity with linkage is not found
>   to refer to some other declaration, then that entity is a member of
>   the innermost enclosing namespace. However such a declaration does not
>   introduce the member name in its namespace scope.

The declaration in your example declares `n::another_function`.

Comment: +1 -- this answer is more complete than mine. Leaving mine because it still has that useful example though.

Answer (score 3):

According to N3485 7.3.1 [namespace.def]/6, the correct answer is `n::another_function`.

> The enclosing namespaces of a declaration are those namespaces in
>   which the declaration lexically appears, except for a redeclaration of
>   a namespace member outside its original namespace (e.g., a definition
>   as specified in 7.3.1.2). Such a redeclaration has the same enclosing
>   namespaces as the original declaration. [ Example:
>
> ```
> namespace Q {
>     namespace V {
>         void f(); // enclosing namespaces are the global namespace, Q, and Q::V
>         class C { void m(); };
>     }
>     void V::f() { // enclosing namespaces are the global namespace, Q, and Q::V
>         extern void h(); // ... so this declares Q::V::h
>     }
>     void V::C::m() { // enclosing namespaces are the global namespace, Q, and Q::V
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> —end example ]