# Which namespace does the extern declaration refer?

Tags: c++, gcc, namespaces, language-lawyer, extern

I found an inconsistent behavior of the `Q_INIT_RESOURCE()` macros in Qt, where it may fail if being compiled with GCC.

Consider the code:

```cpp
do {
    extern void func();
    func();
}
while(false);
```

Here we declare an external function and call it: so far so good. That is the approach that the macros is using under the hood. Now let's try to call this code from two different functions, one in a namespace, the other in the global namespace:

```cpp
void funcGlobal() {
    do {
        extern void func();
        func();
    }
    while(false);
}

namespace ns {
void funcNamespace() {
    do {
        extern void func();
        func();
    }
    while(false);
}
}

void func() { std::cout << 1; }

namespace ns {
void func() { std::cout << 2; }
}
```

As I can see, MSVC calls the `::func()` in both cases, but GCC calls `::func()` from the global function and `ns::func()` from the `functionNamespace`. Intuitively I find MSVC more consistent, but my question is: what does the standard say, and which compiler is correct?

Regarding the macros: due to the problem above calling the macros `Q_INIT_RESOURCE()` from any function that is not in the global namespace causes the compiler error. I have to fix that using an additional level of indirection, wrapping the usage of the macros into a global function.

Comment: Earlier dup target https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14144953/local-function-declaration-inside-namespace

Comment: [Note: As the resource initializers generated by rcc are declared in the global namespace, your calls to Q_INIT_RESOURCE() also need to be done outside of any namespace.](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/resources.html)

Comment: @LanguageLawyer Thank you, that answers my question.